# Split a Netmask into little chunks

Tags: subnet

I would like to know how I could divide a Netmask like 255.255.255.192 in 8 parts.

Would it be something like this:

255.255.255.192
255.255.255.128
255.255.255.0

I'm really confused.

Comment: I'm confused, I have a network and its mask is 255.255.255.192 and I want to split this network in 8 parts. So the mask would still be 255.255.255.192, because I'm dividing the network,

Comment: 8 equal parts means you need to shorten the network mask by 3 bits. Have you read the linked Q&A? It'll remove *a lot* of your confusion.

Comment: I got it, so it becomes a /29 255.255.255.248. Thank you